# Ubuntu 17.04 Installer not connecting seeing any wireless networks?

Tags: wireless, system-installation, 17.04, wifi-hardware-switch

It's somewhat bizarre because on the first attempt it did see all the wireless networks around me.  I then put in the password for mine and attempted to complete the install.  However it could not connect.  I restarted the install, and now it does not attempt to connect to any WIFI network at all.  If I boot into live, the enable wifi option in the top launcher is completely gone.  Thoughts?

Comment: I remade the USB installer and now it works.  Apparently it's possible for the installer to get corrupted.    The other issue that was happening even without a network install is it would hang on configuring apt.  Related issue here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/919857/ubuntu-17-04-installation-hangs-on-configuring-apt

Comment: It would be great if USB installer installs could verify their own integrity before attempting an install.